# Firebase ecommerce dashboard

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

Recently we have been moving our iOS Project's analytics from Google Analytics to Firebase. Everything is migrating good, until Enhanced Ecommerce. I came against these APIs in GTM and found out how to implement Enhanced Ecommerce using Firebase.

[Google Tag Manager - Enhanced Ecommerce](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5/enhanced-ecommerce)

Then I have been looking for the dashboard where I could see the conversions, but I couldn't find any on Firebase. After searching a bit I assume that it's just through Firebase and the dashboard will be same as the previous Google Analytic Console.

Questions:

1. Does the GTM enhanced ecommerce uses the Google Analytics Console's Ecommerce section to show the conversions.
2. Will we be using 2 different dashboards, Firebase's and Google Analytics because we will be needing Google Analytics Console for Ecommerce only.

Answer (score 1):

1) Firebase acts as a data layer for GTM to push data on the GA dashboard. So all firebase data passed via GTM providing a GA tag and Enabling Enhanced Ecommerce Features, will let you add enhanced ecommerce events. Take a look at this [doc](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5/enhanced-ecommerce).

2) Yes, for the purpose of reporting enhanced ecommerce through Firebase, you need to see the reports in GA. You can go ahead and file a feature request to Firebase Support with detailed use case.