# Firebase eCommerce analytics for react-native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to log some eCommerce data into Firebase analytics, I'm using these events to log,

**view_item_list, add_to_cart, begin_checkout, add_payment_info, purchase** etc.

I could find these logs on the dashboard, But I couldn't find any eCommerce report with these data. Am I missing anything? Should I configure anything on the Firebase console in order to view the ecommerce report?

These are the example objects I logged.

```
 let item_jeggings: any = {
  item_id: 'SKU_123',
  item_name: 'jeggings',
  item_category: 'pants',
  item_variant: 'black',
  item_brand: 'Google',
  price: 9.99
};
    let item_boots: any = {
  item_id: 'SKU_456',
  item_name: 'boots',
  item_category: 'shoes',
  item_variant: 'brown',
  item_brand: 'Google',
  price: 24.99
};
const params1 = {
  item_list_id: 'L001',
  item_list_name: 'Related products',
  items: [item_jeggings, item_boots]
};
analytics().logEvent('view_item_list', params1);
```

Events are logging fine on to the console. But where can I find the eCommerce analytics?

**Edit**

Seems currently there is no option in Firebase to view the eCommerce report. Since we can link the firebase project with google analytics & google analytcs, can we use the google analytics to view the eCommerce report which has been logged via Firebase?

If not, Which is the best way to log/see the eCommerce report in a react-native application?

[image]

Comment: The answer here seems to suggest that you have to use Google Analytics to watch the ecommerce events from Firebase: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610677/firebase-ecommerce-dashboard

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen I tried that too. But couldn't find those data there. I am able to see the events there. But failed to find out the ecommerce data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firebase acts as a data layer for GTM to push data on the Google Analytics dashboard. So all firebase data passed via GTM providing a GA tag and Enabling Enhanced Ecommerce Features**

you can see events on tag manager

[image]

you can enable enhanced ecommerce like this

[image]

You can Enable enhance ecommerce like below

[image]

you can choose `Conversions > Ecommerce > Sales Performance` to see the report

[image]

For more information you can see this [VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgLGWvhOyHU)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But when I linked the Firebase project with Google analytic console, the property is created with type App+Web which doesn't have the last column(create view) like you specified in the first image. Is the image you refered is from a normal website? Or a linkedobile app project from firebase?

Comment: I've added my admin settings screenshot.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi sorry I did not check this on mobile. I just tested on the web. I am a little busy now. I will find the option for app+web and edit my answer

Comment: did you setup ios, android, and web?

Comment: Actually I configured both Android & iOS projects in Firebase . When I linked that project with the google analytic, app+web property type is automatically created.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi you have to setup again android, ios and web like this https://ibb.co/YpwFt4D

Comment: After linking the project with Google analytics?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi I did not find any option with app+web. can you try this with the only web

Comment: That is not possible. Like I said, it is automatically created while I liked the firebase project with google analytics